# Acestramengine issue - related with __m2crypto

Tags: python-2.7, kodi

I have Arch linux. When I try to open acestreamengine, I got this error:

```
$ sudo acestreamengine --client-console
2017-07-15 10:36:06,535|MainThread|acestream|error during startup
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "core.c", line 1590, in 
   File "core.c", line 144, in 
   File "core.c", line 2, in

ImportError: cannot import name __m2crypto
```

Currently I have version m2crypto-26-0

Someone can help me? I can not start the engine.
Thanks
Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't downgrade M2Crypto version you can put it's earlier version to the Acestream lib directory.

For example, you can download M2Crypto from https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/p/python2-m2crypto/python2-m2crypto-0.23.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz and move M2Crypto* directories from `usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` folder to `<acestream_home>/lib`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an earlier version of M2Crypto.
Version 0.23 works just fine.
I'm using Slackware 14.2